# Multiple CSS keyframe animation with delay on SVG paths

Tags: css, animation, svg

I am trying to use CSS3 keyframes to animate an SVG object. The SVG contains 13 paths. First I want each path to appear with .1s delay after the other, and then stay visible (using strokes). When all 13 paths have appeared I want them all to be filled simultaneously using another keyframe, however since I am already using `animation-delay` to have the paths appear, I am unsure on how to fill them all at once with the other keyframe.

I have below CSS code right now. Is there another method to achieve what I want?

```
path {
    stroke: #ccc;
    stroke-width: 5px;
    animation: appear .3s 1;
    /* animation: fill 1s 1; */
    animation-fill-mode: both;
}

path:nth-child(1), 
path:nth-child(2) { animation-delay: .1s }      
path:nth-child(3) { animation-delay: .2s }      
path:nth-child(4) { animation-delay: .3s }      
path:nth-child(5) { animation-delay: .4s }      
path:nth-child(6) { animation-delay: .5s }      
path:nth-child(7) { animation-delay: .6s }      
path:nth-child(8) { animation-delay: .7s }      
path:nth-child(9) { animation-delay: .8s }      
path:nth-child(10) { animation-delay: .9s }     
path:nth-child(11) { animation-delay: 1s }      
path:nth-child(12) { animation-delay: 1.1s }    
path:nth-child(13) { animation-delay: 1.2s }    

@keyframes appear { 
    from { opacity:0; } 
    to { opacity:1; } 
}

@keyframes fill {
    from { fill: none }
    to { fill: #ccc }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing it would be grouping the paths in a `<g>`element and apply the fill animation to the group:

```
g{fill:none;animation: fill 1s 1 .7s forwards; }
```

Next a working example with only 7 paths. You can use the same logic for 13 paths.

```css
path {
    stroke: #ccc;
    stroke-width: 5px;
    animation: appear .3s 1;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

path:nth-child(1), 
path:nth-child(2) { animation-delay: .1s }      
path:nth-child(3) { animation-delay: .2s }      
path:nth-child(4) { animation-delay: .3s }      
path:nth-child(5) { animation-delay: .4s }      
path:nth-child(6) { animation-delay: .5s }      
path:nth-child(7) { animation-delay: .6s }  

g{fill:none;animation: fill 1s 1 .7s forwards; }
  

@keyframes appear { 
    from { opacity:0; } 
    to { opacity:1; } 
}

@keyframes fill {
    from { fill: none; }
    to { fill: #f00; }
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 120 30">
  <g>
  <path d="M10,11h8v8h-8z"/>
  <path d="M25,11h8v8h-8z"/>
  <path d="M40,11h8v8h-8z"/>
  <path d="M55,11h8v8h-8z"/>
  <path d="M70,11h8v8h-8z"/>
  <path d="M85,11h8v8h-8z"/>
  <path d="M100,11h8v8h-8z"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```